# Winamp trashed its local media library database when I blocked it on my firewall -- Is this supposed to happen?

Tags: firewall, winamp

<strike>Frankly, I don't see a compelling reason why Winamp needs to be using my network, as all I do is listen to songs from my local media.  However, it appears to exact revenge when I try to ensure it can't on my firewall by completely eradicating my media library list (which includes all my song ratings and such).  I was not able to recover this data, as I hadn't exported the database prior, and the actual database file was completely wiped.  My other playlists and the actual media itself appear not to be effected, though.</strike>

Is this supposed to happen, by chance?

*Edit:* I wasn't able to get it to replicate this behavior with a different firewall+Winamp version.  Hmm.

Comment: If winamp was storing your info on a server and was told to delete data on the event of losing the connection to that server yes. but no, i see no reason why that should have happened. other than malicious ones, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Of course i can't guarantee anything, but i guarantee this is not intended behavior.

i guarantee it was a bug.

---

i got this today, not at all related to firewalls or networks. It's a bug:

[image]